# Mock bottle.request object in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, bottle, python-unittest

I am using [bottle](/questions/tagged/bottle) framework. I have code like

```
from bottle import request

def abc():
    x = request.get_header('x')
    ...
    ...
    data = request.json()
    ...
    ...
```

I am writing UTs for this function, I want to mock `get_header` and `json` of [`bottle.request`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.10/api.html#the-request-object), and return my mock data from that.

I tried.

```
from mock import patch

@patch('bottle.request.headers', return_value={'x': 'x'})
@patch('bottle.request.json', return_value=...)
def test_abc(self, _, __):
    ...
    ...
```

But it gives error for `request.headers` is read-only. I also have to mock `request.json`.

Thanks for help in advance :).

Comment: Mock the actual `request` object and give it appropriate `json` and `headers` attributes.

Comment: @AlexHall, Thanks for reply. If I mock entire `request` object then I have to mock many attribute of same. Is there any way to mock only 1-2 attribute then its good option.

Comment: @AlexHallI tried `request = Mock(headers={'x': 'x'}, json={})` but it fails. :(

Comment: My mistake, since your test uses the `get_header` method you would need to mock that, not the headers attribute. Similarly `json` needs to be a function, not directly a dict. Alternatively don't use mocks for this: actually start a server and make requests to it, or use http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webtest/en/latest/. I don't see why you need to 'fake' requests. There's no significant network overhead to make requests locally.

Comment: This module has already written some UT, I have to just add new UT for function which I implemented. I don't know why they are not start server. Is there any way to run bottle app for testing ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Unfortunately I know little about both mock and bottle, so someone else might be able to make a better suggestion. My best idea for you is to have one function which does no actual logic, just extracts headers and stuff and calls another function, and the other function does the actual work but knows nothing about requests. Then just test the latter function. It's hard to get the requests stuff wrong so it's not super important to test it, and this will also make your code nicer in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Check the source code of bottle, headers and json are like:

```
    @DictProperty('environ', 'bottle.request.headers', read_only=True)
    def headers(self):
        ''' A :class:`WSGIHeaderDict` that provides case-insensitive access to
            HTTP request headers. '''
        return WSGIHeaderDict(self.environ)
```

So in my pytest cases, I patched request.environ like below:

```
def test_xxx(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setitem(request.environ, 'bottle.request.json', {'name': 'xxx', 'version': '0.1'})
    add_xxx()
    assert
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy alternative, to mock a bottle request, could be to inject it into your function:

```
from bottle import request

def abc(_request=None):
    if _request is not None:
      request = _request

    x = request.get_header('x')
    ...
    ...
    data = request.json()
    ...
    ...
```

This should be safe as your test code can call your view with a fake request object directly and your production code will skip the conditional.

I  am NOT sure how this works with url routes with named params, as I've never used bottle.

Comment: thanks, but if I change function signature, I have to justify to my manager, why I changed :(. Is there any way to mock without changing function signature ?

Comment: it gives `Read-Only property`. Here is error trace `if self.read_only: raise AttributeError("Read-Only property.")
AttributeError: Read-Only property.`

Comment: It written in `bottle.py` in such a way that, its read only :(

Answer (score -1):

Use Boddle https://github.com/keredson/boddle

```
def test_abc(self, _, __):
    with boddle(headers={'x':'x'}):
        # tests
```